# Why this SQL Query is incorrect

Tags: sql

[image]

```
WITH order_max AS
(
    SELECT order_id, MAX(quantity) max_quantity 
    FROM OrdersDetails
    GROUP BY order_id
),
order_avg AS 
( 
    SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity)/COUNT(*) avg_quantity 
    FROM OrdersDetails
    GROUP BY order_id
)
SELECT order_max.order_id
FROM order_max 
JOIN order_avg 
GROUP BY order_max.order_id 
HAVING max_quantity > avg_quantity
```

This is the error I keep getting:

> Unknown column 'max_quantity' in 'having clause'

But when I do

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_max 
JOIN order_avg 
GROUP BY order_max.order_id 
HAVING max_quantity > avg_quantity
```

it shows the result, I am confused.

Comment: The `max_quantity`  and `avg_quantity` columns in your having clause were defined in different subqueries; So,
It's not valid there.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by define differently?

Comment: A column alias cannot be used to refer to a column that was specified at a different level of the query hierarchy.
 `max_quantity `and `avg_quantity` are your column aliases; you are trying to use in a different level of the query hierarchy

Comment: I see but I still don't understand when I can't reference alias from the CTE table in the having statement here.

Comment: [Please replace images of text with just the text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) see also [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Hi @Mustard, I don't think max_quantity> avg_quantity should only return order_id 1, 3. By simple math,  max _quantity should be always greater than avg_quantity unless quantity for all order items are the same. Could you further explain in text on what the output is for?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/IBlAFx_l

Answer (score 2):

You *could* stick with your current approach by adding an `ON` clause to the join and then adding proper aliases:

```sql
SELECT om.order_id
FROM order_max om
INNER JOIN order_avg oa
    ON oa.order_id = om.order_id
WHERE om.max_quantity > oa.avg_quantity;
```

However, a better approach would be to ditch the CTEs and just use a single pass aggregation query with assertions in the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT order_id
FROM OrdersDetails
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING MAX(quantity) > SUM(quantity) / COUNT(*);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `max_quantity` and `avg_quantity` columns in your having clause were defined in different subqueries; So, It's not valid there.

Change your `HAVING` clause to this :

```
HAVING MAX(order_max.quantity) > AVG(order_avg.avg_quantity);
```

Here a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b562e/27) where I re-wrote your query using CTE and having clause.

```
WITH order_max AS
(
    SELECT order_id, MAX(quantity) max_quantity 
    FROM OrdersDetails
    GROUP BY order_id
),
order_avg AS 
( 
    SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity)/COUNT(*) avg_quantity 
    FROM OrdersDetails
    GROUP BY order_id
)
SELECT order_max.order_id
FROM order_max
INNER JOIN order_avg
    ON order_max.order_id = order_avg.order_id
GROUP BY order_max.order_id, order_max.max_quantity, order_avg.avg_quantity
HAVING (order_max.max_quantity > order_avg.avg_quantity);
```

Which gives me the output as :

```
order_id
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, what do you mean by defined in different subqueries, why I can't use the alias from another subquery in here in having statement?

Comment: you can't use aliases like that elsewhere in a query than the subquery they been defined. You'll have to replicate the whole alias definition.

Comment: Please refer the order of operations :
https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/

Comment: Ok so it's because of the order of how the query being executed?

Comment: Yes @Mustard; 
Also; I have re-written your query using CTE and `Having` clause.